# Decision is not being evaluated in Flow resulting it in passing every time

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, record, screen-flow

I am new to flows and have a  record triggered flow whereby when a ServiceAppointment Record is updated or created that it sends the record ID to an Apex action. This works just fine.

I have to modify it whereby only service appointments with RecordType.DeveloperName in equal either **HD_VT_Service_Appointment**, **Field_Service**, or **Scheduling**

This is what I did:

[image]

I added a get records and a decision panel before the apex action.

My get records panel:

[image]

[image]

My decision panel:

[image]

Everytime I go to debug this and use a service appointment both with a valid developer name and an invalid one, it is executing the flow successfully. I am new to flows and may be missing something simple.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jini, Can you confirm what excatly you are trying to achieve this flow and how you are testing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the flow mentioned above there is no need to get the record type  values using get element.You can directly add the decision box as below.

[image]

In the flow which you made you have just queried the record types on that object and checking if that particular record type is present on that object but you are not checking if record belongs to particular record type because of which it is passing decision box every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added get records initially as I thought it was the only way to get related developer name.